# Why ExceptionInInitializerError when submitting Spark application in YARN cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, mapr

I am using spark "Spark 1.6.1-mapr-1604 " version. 
My job in local mode executes successfully but when I launch same job in yarn cluster mode it throws `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

**Local mode command:**

```
spark-submit --class com.ts.clustering.TrainModel \
ts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
-model /user/hive/warehouse/ts/clustering_model 
-ip /user/hive/warehouse/ts/aidata_seq/* 
-k 10 -ite 10 > app_2.log &
```

**Yarn cluster mode:**

```
spark-submit --queue dev --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--class com.ts.clustering.TrainModel ts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
-model /user/hive/warehouse/ts/clustering_model \
-ip /user/hive/warehouse/ts/aidata_seq/* -k 10 -ite 10 > app_2.log &
```

`-model` parameter is the output location for model to be saved.

The exception in cluster mode:

```
2016-08-29 17:18:46,312 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager: 
  Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ******************): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.ts.clustering.TrainModel$2.call(TrainModel.java:71)
        at com.ts.clustering.TrainModel$2.call(TrainModel.java:67)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1015)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:284)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:401)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
        at com.ts.clustering.TrainModel.<clinit>(TrainModel.java:35)
        ... 21 more
```

I have gone through couple of similar posts but nothing helped. Any suggestion would be great help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as lacking of MVCE and falling under the off-topic rule "why isn't my code working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace I could spot the following:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:401)
  at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
  at com.ts.clustering.TrainModel.(TrainModel.java:35)
  ... 21 more
```

That's easy to say that you did not specify master URL yet you've started the application using `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`.

I'm **guessing** that you've hardcoded the master URL to be `local` or did not specify it at all. See `TrainModel.java:35`.

Comment: i have not specified master url at all. My other spark jobs are working fine without master url.

Comment: What's at `TrainModel.java:71`?

Comment: I asked about the specific line in `TrainModel` at line 71. What's there? Can you show the lines 71 and 35 of `TrainModel`?

Comment: What's the parameter `-model /user/hive/warehouse/ts/clustering_model` for? Is this to read a model from or write one to?

Comment: I think that the OP ought looking for yarn logs as well. I'm afraid that Spark logs aren't enough to debug apps running on yarn.

Comment: I think the the OP may have saved this model and then tried to load it without SC inited. I'm still expecting to find something in the code.